# Bar plot x axis is messy using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Bar plot x axis is getting very messy , I have also rotated the angle but it is still very messy any help would be appreciated.

this is the code

```
ax=yearresult.plot(kind='bar',x='BBB',y='AAA')
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
ax.legend(["AAA", "BBB"]);
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You simply cannot plot 100 categories in a bar chart. Try getting the top 10.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that you should think about representing the data in a different way, if you *really* need everything to be seen

Answer (score 0):

you cannot plot 100 categories in a bar chart it will not be clear.
 Try getting the top 15 like this:

```
 top_15 = df.AA.value_counts().iloc[:15]
 sns.countplot(x = "AA", data = df, order=top_15.index);
```

and no need for legend in that case